# Eclipse plugin "Operation not enabled" 

Tags: java, refactoring, eclipse-plugin

I'm struggling with Java Refactoring - I need to write an Eclipse plug-in which will refactor some code. It's really difficult for me and it would be way easier if I could follow working code step - by - step. The only alike example I could find is a sample [Introduce Indirection](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Unleashing-the-Power-of-Refactoring/index.html).

Unfortunately I cannot make it actually work. I get "chosen operation is not currently available" information anytime I try it.

I've imported code, "Run As -> Eclipse App" and than tried to use Introduce Ind. from Eclipse Articles. What am I doing wrong?

I'll be happy with any help :).

Answer (score 8):

Check your handler class for isEnabled() method. I suppose when creating new handler the default value for this method returns false. That can be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get that example (as written) working, or perhaps you need to open a bug.  When you start their example in Run As, is there any errors in your error log?

Something else you can try is to look at some of the workbench refactorings.  See org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.MoveResourcesHandler which sets up the move resources refactoring, and http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_a_particular_class_from_an_Eclipse_plug-in%3F if you need help tracking down the SDK classes using CTRL+SHIFT+T

Comment: I've managed to run it. For others who'll have same problem, I'll write what helped me:

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to run it. For others who'll face the same problem:

Check the basics:
Remember that you can chose only one method and:
It must exist in the model (http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaElement.html)

It must not have any errors

Must not be a constructor

Must not be connected to annotation declaration

And:Select a Java method in the editor outline or the Package Explorer

And it gets obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

The action handler class should be impediments with related interfaces (Check for error console for identify what are the missing interfaces, most probably this would be 'IActionDelegate').